# Python import problem with Django management commands

Tags: python, django, import

For whatever reason, when I was new to Python and Django, I wrote some import statements like this at the top of a models.py file:

```
from django.contrib import auth
```

And I'd use it like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
    # ...
```

This worked fine. A long time later, I wrote a custom management command, and it would do this:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
```

When I ran my custom command (`python manage.py my_command`) this would result in Python complaining that the module `auth` had no attribute `models` on the line declaring the `ForeignKey` in models.py.

To work around this problem, I changed my models.py to the more usual:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # ...
```

Can someone explain to me what I am missing? Is there something different in the environment when you run a management command? Or was I just doing it wrong the whole time? Thanks!

**Edit**: Following dmitko's hunch about circular imports, here are the imports used in my models.py file. I'm showing the original import of `auth` commented out, along with the only model that has a foreign key to the auth user model:

```
import datetime  
from django.db import models 
# from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class UserLastVisit(models.Model):
    # user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, unique=True)
    #                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # after adding mgmt command, error occurred here; change to the line below
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    last_visit = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

And here are the imports of the management command that uncovered the problem:

```
import datetime   
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand 
from core.models import UserLastVisit, AnonLastVisit, Statistic
```

Was this setting up a circular import type situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If some random module ever imports module `x.y.z`, then a later person who imports just `x.y` will see a `z` in the `x.y` namespace.

The reason this happens is that `import x.y.z` is actually three import statements in one.  It works something like this:

```
x = __internal_import('x')
x.y = __internal_import('x/y')
x.y.z = __internal_import('x/y/z')
```

Next time someone does `__internal_import('x/y')`, they'll get the same object, because python is smart enough not to import the same one twice.  That object already has its `z` member assigned to the `z` module.

In your full app, probably you had a module that did `import django.contrib.auth.models`.  But your minimal standalone program didn't import that module, so the name was never assigned.

(Note: there's no such thing as `__internal_import`.  It's just an illustration.  The real function has some other name that you would have to look up.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you do `from django.contrib import auth` that means you're importing auth package as a module and what it exports is driven by `__init__.py` in the auth folder:

```
>>> from django.contrib import auth
>>> dir(auth)
['BACKEND_SESSION_KEY', 'ImproperlyConfigured', 'REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME', 'SESSION_
KEY', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__path__', 'authentica
te', 'datetime', 'get_backends', 'get_user', 'import_module', 'load_backend', 'l
ogin', 'logout']
```

You can check `__init__.py` in `django\contrib\auth` and see the same function list. When you import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` that means that you're importing a submodule from the `auth` package and it works.

BTW. I was unable to use `auth.models.User` in any case - whether I run from console or from my django app.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for the reply, I will study this some more. I wish I could explain why using `auth.models.User` worked for me before I wrote the management command, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what's going on without seeing the new manage.py command that you added.  However, I often see the " has no attribute " in cases with circular imports, and it's almost always fixed by changing the module-level imports to function- or class-level imports, as you did here.  You might check if anything like that is going on here.

Comment: I have edited my question, showing what I hope is the relevant parts of the code. I don't think there was a circular import going on, but do you see anything suspicious?